# How to ensure set type value in EditText to be only receive only int?

Tags: android, try-catch, android-edittext

I want to calculate from 2 input (2 [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)) which the value in EditText receive only int.
How to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding android:numeric="decimal" to EditText

Answer (score 0):

Use int myInt = Integer.parseInt("55"); 
Where 55 is the text that was entered in the edittext. 
If it is an integer in the text it will work; otherwise it will throw NumberFormatException  if the string cannot be parsed as an integer value.